# Is there a difference in meaning between "not to make" and "to make no"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I was asked today whether

> In order to make no mistakes

was correct. I said yes, but that I found it a bit strange and that I would rather use

> In order not to make mistakes

The outcome is the same, but I sense a difference in meaning. Is there really one?

Comment: The second expresses a purpose to avoid *a number* of possible mistakes. The first expresses a purpose to avoid *even one, first* mistake.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Would they be equivalent if the second said _not to make **any** mistakes_?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I should think so, but then the second becomes the wordier option for saying the same thing.(The first has a nice anapestic rhythm going on, too, don't you think?)

Comment: Negatives, like other operators in English, may be placed immediately before their focussed constituent (like the NP _mistakes_ here), **or** immediately before any constituent that contains the focussed constituent (like the VP _make mistakes_ here). When it's used as a determiner in a noun phrase, the negative form is _no_; but when it's an adverb modifying a VP, it's _not_. If you know German, _no_ as a noun modifier works just like _kein_, but the construction isn't nearly as common in English as it is in German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct and acceptable.

"In order to make no mistakes" implies that you have a target of zero mistakes, which isn't as strict as the latter.

Comment: Another expression to consider would be "in order to avoid mistakes".

Comment: That was my feeling too, but I could not express it in words. Thank you!